# error: variable or field ‘myfunction’ declared void

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors

In the following, I haven't defined the type `doesntexist`.

```
void myfunction(doesntexist argument)
{
}
```

GCC 4.7.2 says "`error: variable or field ‘myfunction’ declared void`"

My question is this: *What's going through the compilers mind here to refer to the function name being void and not the argument type?*

[*EDIT*]
Before downvoting, be aware the answer to this issue is related to **the order of the errors and `-Wfatal-errors` stopping the more immediately relevant message from being printed**. This is not simply me having a go at a slightly vague compiler message.

Comment: My gcc 4.7.2 says "error: unknown type name 'doesntexist'". I think an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) might be in order.

Comment: Please show the *complete* and *unedited* error log.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bbe3a44df482b5a

Comment: @MarkGarcia If compiled with gcc, your code would result in an error, because those are c++ libraries.

Comment: `refer to the function name being void and not the argument type?` Compiler didn't said that. It recognized `myfunction` not as function, but as variable and said that this variable declared with type `void` (you can't have variables of type `void` in C and C++). Next line compiler states exact reason of why this happened: `‘doesntexist’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: An update on my earlier comment: when I compile the code as C, I get the message I quoted eariler; when compiled as C++, the code gives the error you cite followed by `error: 'doesntexist' was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: [Compiled as C](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/056138fd14fd75e7). How do you compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks, @JoachimPileborg. The unedited error log didn't contain anything useful, and it should have! The comment lead me to the issue and solution... **remove `-Wfatal-errors` from my makefile**.

```
19:17 >>> gcc -Wfatal-errors main.c
main.c:2:17: error: variable or field ‘myfunction’ declared void
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

and removing `-Wfatal-errors`...

```
19:18 >>> gcc main.c 
main.c:2:17: error: variable or field ‘myfunction’ declared void
main.c:2:17: error: ‘doesntexist’ was not declared in this scope
```

Problem solved.

---

For those who say *"why use* `-Wfatal-errors` *in the first place?"*: I usually don't want *all* the errors as the first can trigger the rest. In this case it looks like the errors are given out of order, or at least in an unexpected order - I assume the compiler would run into the `‘doesntexist’ was not declared` error first.

Answer (score 2):

Its definitely not the problem with the function being `void` type, possibly `g++` compiler poor error message schema when the function parameters consists unknown type.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @jozxyqk  you need to specify a type for the argument, if what you have in [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bbe3a44df482b5a)  is properly representative of your code what you need to do is provide a valid datatype for the argument, something like `void myfunc(string argument)` or `void myfunc(int argument)` etc.

There is a decent resource on datatypes [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm), and another [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/).  It may be worth doing a [Google](http://www.google.com) search for [how to use data types in c++](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how%20to%20use%20data%20types%20in%20c%2b%2b&oq=how%20to%20use%20data%20types%20in%20c%2b%2b&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.625j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or similar so yu can find some reading material on them and their usage.

[Linked here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98d37f23c39ea28b) is a modified version which shows a string as a valid datatype for an argument and an overloaded version for an int argument.

Let me know if you need more information:)